# Adding an image to UITableViewCell in edit mode isn't aligning properly

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, edit

I am using the code below to try to get the this look:

[image]

but instead it looks like:

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in

    }
    deleteRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    deleteRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "DeleteIcon.png")!)
    return [deleteRowAction]
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
deleteRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "DeleteIcon.png")!)
```

to:

```
deleteRowAction.image = UIImage(named: "DeleteIcon.png")
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In below IOS 11 , editActionsForRowAt methods show the patter image on in background, and pattern image is repeated if image is small then cell size.
That's why use the third party for implement this [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit)

And if you implement this in IOS 11 then use this UITableViewDelegate function, It work perfectly Example:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            // Call edit action

            // Reset state
            success(true)
        })
        deleteAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Delete")
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
        let value = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        value.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
        return value
    }
```